# Unable to select table id in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0, asp.net-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as `getElementByID` not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Apologize for the silly question, but I am not getting what I want.
I am using following code to change visibility of table.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   document.getElementById('<%= tblEnablePreferredZerker.ClientID %>').style.display = "none";
</script>
<table class="style1" id="tblEnablePreferredZerker" >
   <tr></tr>
</table>
```

Is there any mistake? or any other method to do this?
Or can it be easily possible with jQuery?
Thanks,

Comment: Try to put `script` tag after the `table` tag.

Comment: @ryadavilli: Still error occuring. "The name 'tblEnablePreferredZerker' does not exist in the current context"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to access this id of table with ClientID which is not server accessible, You need to add runat="server" in table tag.

```
<table class="style1" id="tblEnablePreferredZerker" runat="server">
   <tr></tr>
</table>
```

You are `trying to access the element that is not yet available`. Put your script just after the table you are try to access or before the `closing body tag` so that you have every html element ready before use. You can also use [`document.ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) jquery event if you want to place before your html element.

Putting script below the element you want to access.

```
<table class="style1" id="tblEnablePreferredZerker" >
   <tr></tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
   document.getElementById('<%= tblEnablePreferredZerker.ClientID %>').style.display = "none";
</script>
```

Putting script just before closing of body tag

```
<!-- your thml -->

<script type="text/javascript"> 
   document.getElementById('<%= tblEnablePreferredZerker.ClientID %>').style.display = "none";
</script>
</body>
```

Using jQuery [document.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $(document).ready(function() {
      document.getElementById('<%= tblEnablePreferredZerker.ClientID %>').style.display =  "none";
   });       
</script>
```

Comment: But I am using master page so here is no body tag?

Comment: Use document.ready, I have updated my answer, see last section.

Comment: I have used this but still error is there:(

Comment: Your table in not server accessible as you do not have runat="server" add this attribute and check it again.

Answer (score 1):

Enclose your script in `$(document).ready()` because the element doesn't exist when the script runs. & be sure to include jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#<%= tblEnablePreferredZerker.ClientID %>').hide();
   });
</script>
<table class="style1" id="tblEnablePreferredZerker" >
   <tr></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @Engineer hm. I just added `$(document).ready()` without modifying the code.
Will edit my answer now. thanks

Comment: Still getting error- "The name 'tblEnablePreferredZerker' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: @RajeevDiboliya Well, seems an error in your asp code, though I dont know much of asp. This would work (without asp): 
`$('#tblEnablePreferredZerker').hide();`

Answer (score 0):

You have tagged jQuery so you might as well use it.

You can use `$(document).ready()` like so:

```
/* load jQuery first! */
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        document.getElementById('<%= tblEnablePreferredZerker.ClientID %>').style.display = "none";
    });
</script>
```

This will fire only when all elements in this document are loaded.